# Managing EF Code First Migrations between Development and Production

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.3, entity-framework-migrations

**Very briefly:**

I was implementing EF Migrations on an existing project built as Code First based on an article by [Ladislav Mrnka](http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2012/03/ef-4-3-migrations-and-existing-database/)

When implementing EF Migrations on a project that is already into production, how can Migration scripts be managed between updates applied to Development and then Scripts generated for Production?

The reason I'm baffled is that the MigrationId generated for each script had a TimeStamp appended to it. In my migration attempts, I noticed that the entries recorded within the __MigrationHistory tables on dev and prod were different, thus raising the question, if the DB were to go through quite a few Migration Upgrades, then if ever a Downgrade was required for any reason, It would be very difficult to co-relate the exact MigrationId for creating the scripts using `update-database -script`

---

Very straight forward process where you create an `$InitialMigration` that creates the `__MigrationHistory` table. Then any changes to your Model are followed by any `update-database` to get the database *Migrated*. And this process cycles whenever you have a logically grouped batch of Model changes.

A look into the `__MigrationHistory` table showed

```
+------------------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|            MigrationId             |        CreatedOn        |                              Model                               | ProductVersion |
+------------------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+
| 000000000000000_BootstrapMigration | 2012-03-01 17:40:39.567 | 0x1F8B08000000400ECBD07601C49...HASH_TRUNCATED...CA7F54A20F50000 | 4.3.1          |
| 201203011745335_AutomaticMigration | 2012-03-01 17:45:33.557 | 0x1F8B08000000400ECBD07601C49...HASH_TRUNCATED...F4AE3681EF50000 | 4.3.1          |
+------------------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: How exactly did you achieve that timestamps in prod and dev database are different? Are you using database initializer for DB upgrade?

Comment: Initially, after enabling migrations on a stable build, I ran `update-database` to create the migrations table with a 00_bootstrap entry. Now I changed the Model and ran `Update-Database -Script` to generate the script for Production DB, followed by `Update-Database` to get the Dev DB migrated. Now executing the sql generated by the prior step on the Prod DB creates an entry in the MigrationsHistory table as `TIMESTAMP01_AutomaticMigration`, whereas the later command on the Dev DB inserted an entry in the Dev DB with a different TimeStamp, since the 2 commands were run some moments apart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your comment it looks like the solution is straight forward. If you want to have same timestamp you must use `Update-Database` only once and in your case it means using:

```
Update-Database -Script
```

and executing created script on both databases.

Anyway I would probably not use automatic migrations in scenario where I expect downgrades. I would use code based migrations with explicit name for every migration. In such case every record in `MigrationHistory` table should have unique name and timestamp should not matter.

Comment: Ah, yes, the same script approach makes sense! what I did yesterday was dwell deeper into `Add-Migration` and also creation of proper change scripts as c# files with up and down blocks. (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-automatic-migrations-walkthrough.aspx).

Thanks a lot for your insight though!